# Запятые в неоднородных причастных оборотах

Tags: пунктуация

Обособляются ли запятыми с обеих сторон два неоднородных определения, выраженных причастными оборотами?

Т.е.: Камень, лежащий в коробке(,) является внешне идентичным найденному в горах Тибета.

Нужна ли здесь вторая запятая? Если да, то почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Камень, лежащий в коробке, является внешне идентичным найденному в горах Тибета.

Сравнить: Камень, лежащий в коробке, является внешне идентичным камню, найденному в горах Тибета.

В заданом предложении первый причастный оборот относится к существительному "камень" и обособляется, а второе причастие "найденному" выступает в роли пропущенного существительного и является дополнением.  Между собой они не связаны.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Достаточно доходчиво.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно нужна. Любой оборот должен быть закрыт с двух сторон, если только нет специальных оговорок на союз "и" в сочетании с однородностью, общее слово и т. п.

Alenka13, Вы, похоже, совершенно неверно грамматику этой фразы понимаете. "является" здесь сказуемое. Ну какой еще второй причастный оборот, да еще однородный?! Если оставить одну запятую, это получится одиночная запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым. Такого не бывает.

Видимо, не бывает и того, чтобы причастные обороты, относящиеся к одному слову, шли не подряд. Но это уже детали на фоне первого факта.

Comment: Хорошо, поняла. Спасибо вам!